# Apply Light version of a font when multiple files are uploaded

Tags: mpdf

I am having an issue with applying a Light version of my font, when declaring a custom local font.

This is how I declared it:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
      drupal_get_path('theme', 'my_subtheme') . '/fonts/',
    ]),
    'fontdata' => $fontData + [
        'proxima' => [
          'R' => 'ProximaNovaRegular.ttf',
        ],
        'proxima light' => [
          'R' => 'ProximaNovaLight.ttf',
        ],
        'proxima bold' => [
          'R' => 'ProximaNovaBold.ttf',
        ]
      ],
    'default_font' => 'proxima'
  ]);
```

But whenever I write 'proxima light' in my css the font remains regular.

I also tried with this snippet:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
  'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
    drupal_get_path('theme', 'my_subtheme') . '/fonts/',
  ]),
  'fontdata' => $fontData + [
    'proxima' => [
      'R' => 'ProximaNovaRegular.ttf',
      'B' => 'ProximaNovaBold.ttf',
      'L' => 'ProximaNovaLight.ttf',
    ]
  ],
  'default_font' => 'proxima'
]);
```

But I don't know how to call it and I didn't find a working example on the internet.

If I only declare my Light file, then it makes everything light.

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
      drupal_get_path('theme', 'my_subtheme') . '/fonts/',
    ]),
    'fontdata' => $fontData + [
        'proxima' => [
          'R' => 'ProximaNovaLight.ttf',
        ]
      ],
    'default_font' => 'proxima'
  ]);
```

I really don't know how to continue from here, am I declaring it wrong? The problem is I need all 3 versions of the font.

Comment: What if you define the light font key in config and the css with an underscore? `proxima_light`? will it help?

Comment: @Finwe I have tried that also and it still does not work.